# "Error in knn (...) no missing values are allowed", why?

Tags: r, knn

I have a test set with missing values in the class variable.
When running knn I get the error message:

> "Error in knn (...) no missing values are allowed".

Question: Why doesn't knn allow the values of the class variable in the test set to be missing? I mean, I don't know those values, I want to predict them. 
Can I just assign some class to the class variable and still get the correct result?

Example code:

```
library(class)
data <- data.frame("class_variable"=sample(LETTERS[1:2], 30, replace =     TRUE),
               "predictor_1" = runif(30),
               "predictor_2" = runif(30))
train <- data[1:20,]
test <- data[21:30,]

test$class_variable <- NA

knn(train, test, train$class_variable)
```

> Error in knn(train, test, train$class_variable) : 
>     no missing values are allowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`train` and `test` have to have the same number of columns, and there cannot be NA values in the data. So the way to do it is, exclude the `class_variable` column from both `train` and `test` when passing them to `knn`. This will work:

```
knn(train[, -1], test[, -1], train[, 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the R [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/class/html/knn.html) on kNN, the third argument that the `knn` function takes is the true class values of the *training set*. You are correct that you do not need the true class values of the test set, since that is what you are trying to predict in the first place. But you are not providing `NA` values for the test classifications; you are providing `NA` values for the training classifications. The kNN algorithm cannot *train* on `NA` response values.

Answer (score 0):

As explained the kNN algorithm can't train on NA response values, so please try using %>%drop.na() before splitting your data. That should solve it.

```
library(class)
library(tidyverse)
data <- data.frame("class_variable"=sample(LETTERS[1:2], 30, replace = TRUE),
              "predictor_1" = runif(30),
              "predictor_2" = runif(30))%>%drop_na()

train <- data[1:20,]
test <- data[21:30,]

test$class_variable <- NA

knn(train, test, train$class_variable)
```